# Paging using include in Linq to Entities does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I created an extension method to share my pagination method, the extension method is:

```
public static CustomPaginateResult<TEntity> Paginate<TEntity>(this IPagination pagination, 
            PaginateQueryParameters parameters, IQueryable<TEntity> collection, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy)
            where TEntity : class
{
    var totalRows = collection.Count();
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRows / parameters.Rows);

    var query = collection.Take(parameters.Rows);

    var results = orderBy(query)
        .Skip(parameters.Page * parameters.Rows)
        .ToList();

    var result = new CustomPaginateResult<TEntity>()
    {
        PageSize = parameters.Rows,
        TotalRows = totalRows,
        TotalPages = totalPages,
        CurrentPage = parameters.Page,
        Results = results
    };

    return result;
}
```

When I call this method, if **IQueryable collection** does not include any "include" this works fine, but, if I use any "Include" I only can get data for the first page, but, for the followings pages this not return data. I get the query that is generate and I see that in the sub-query is present the top clausule, I think this is the problem!

Good call:

```
var data = _programRepository.Paginate(new PaginateQueryParameters(page, rows),_programRepository.GetAll(), order => order.OrderBy(c => c.Id));
```

Bad call:

```
var data = _programRepository.Paginate(new PaginateQueryParameters(page, rows),_programRepository.GetAll("CategoriaPrograma"), order => order.OrderBy(c => c.Id));
```

And one query example for the bad case:

```
SELECT *
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (50) *
        FROM [dbo].[Sesion] AS [c] ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Modulo] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[ModuloId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    ORDER BY [Limit1].[Id] ASC
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: are you sure parameters.Rows is defined?

Comment: @GertArnold orderBy is not a sequence it is a function.

Comment: Hi @Hogan, yes, the parameters.Rows is defined and has value

Comment: @GertArnold - this is an extension function that is the type that it extends.  Why implement it as an extension function?  That I can't answer.

Comment: @GertArnold and Hogan, I have an interface IPagination, so, for those entityes that I need paginate, simply, this entity implement this interface, and with the extension method can use the method paginate to do all the work

Comment: Then you better make it a method of the interface and use an abstract base object that implements it as an instance method. It's still "just a method" and it's never recommended to declare parameters (or variables of members or... whatever) without actually using them. It should give you a compiler warning (not error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the Take to be after the Skip. Edited after tip bij @Hogan.

Have you tried this:

```
var results = orderBy(collection)
    .Skip(parameters.Page * parameters.Rows)
    .Take(parameters.Rows)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @MarkHasper, yes, I try this, but does not fix my problem

Comment: this code is wrong it should be `orderby(collection)`